# How to remove a WordPress action which has been added from within a class?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to stop password fields being added automatically to the [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) registration form.

Looking inside Theme My Login's `/theme-my-login/modules/custom-passwords/custom-passwords.php` file, I can see the `password_fields` function gets added to the `register_form` action at approximately line 38. For example:

```
add_action( 'register_form', array( &$this, 'password_fields' ) );
```

I tried removing that action with the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
remove_action( 'register_form', array( Theme_My_Login_Custom_Passwords, 'password_fields' ) );
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is `Theme_My_Login_Custom_Passwords` the class name ?

Comment: Yes it is. `Theme_My_Login_Custom_Passwords` extends `Theme_My_Login_Abstract`

Comment: `If an action has been added from within a class, for example by a plugin, removing it will require accessing the class variable.` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Comment: I know you can do `global $var` but how would I access the class variable in this case?

Comment: I think you need [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57079/12615)